# React testing library unable to find an accessible element with the role "textbox" and name `/username/i`

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this code:

```
const userInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /username/i });
expect(userInput.nodeValue).toBe('someuser');
```

And I get this when running the text. The name is right there, what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I added `screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();` to the code. This prints a url in the terminal when the test is executed.

Put the url in the browser and it opens a testing playground which recommends the query to use.

I discovered the name the code was after was the name I had assigned for the label. Thus, the input attribute `name=bookCost` did not work, but the label text shown in the browser, `'Enter book cost'`, did work.